Logic App SFTP private key authentication doesn't work
I'm trying to create a Logic App that uploads files to a SFTP. When I create a new connection, I get Permission denied (publickey) error.

Using the exact same keyfile from the command line works fine.


We used to have this issue a few times due to whitelisting set up on SFTP side (make sure traffic is not blocked by anything between Logic Apps and SFTP) and a few times when the private key was imported in the key vault incorrectly (make sure there's no copy-paste error, line endings are correct, etc.)

I'm having exactly the same issue which started occurring circa 20th of May. Conencting to the SFTP server from a VM in the same data center as the logic app works just fine. Switching the logic app to a different region does not help.

Curiously, my original logic app is also hosted in Australia East data center

My error
{
"error": {
"code": 502,
"source": "logic-apis-australiaeast.azure-apim.net",
"clientRequestId": "2322c510-b95c-4990-85c0-e0adf997059e",
"message": "BadGateway",
"innerError": {
"status": 502,
"message": "Permission denied (publickey).\r\nclientRequestId: 2322c510-b95c-4990-85c0-e0adf997059e",
"error": {
"message": "Permission denied (publickey)."
},
"source": "sftpwithssh-ae.azconn-ae-001.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
}
}

@NickGoloborodko interesting, I wonder if it is a Microsoft jump server issue. Can you try a ED25519 key?

@Coxy Unfourtinately the SFTP server the logic app is connecting to is controlled by a third party and I can't try a different key type. Also, it appears that creating a standard logic app rather than consumption based one and using a SFTP connector rather than an SFTP - SSH one seems to work. I have not switched to that approach yet, as running the logic app that executes once per day seems like an overkill, so hoping the original issue gets sorted.

@NickGoloborodko I'm actually worried that I'm going to run into the same problem as you - for my POC I control the SFTP server so I could ass the different key, but for the "real thing" I'll be at the vendor's mercy. You might try connecting to the server over a normal SSH session; if it lets you in then you could presumably add your own public key fingerprint to authorized_keys

@Coxy the odd part - everything worked just fine with an RSA key for about 3 years...

As far as I can tell, RSA keys, even if they are in OpenSSH format, do not work in the SSH/SFTP Connector.
I logged into the SSH server, added a new ED25519 key fingerprint to authorized_keys, and pasted the private key ASCII blob into the blade in Azure Portal. That worked.
